# How can I log debugging messages from an IE Browser Helper Object written in C++ in Windows XP-7?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, bho, event-viewer

I'm debugging a browser helper object written in C++ for Internet Explorer. I'm using IE 9 and Windows 7. I'm trying to send debugging messages using logEventLogMessage() which - if I understand this right - should appear somewhere in the windows Event Viewer. But they never do. Could anybody please tell me what I have to do to see these log messages?

EDIT: The first two replies made me think a bit and I'm changing the question from "How do I turn on Internet Explorer 9 event logging in Windows 7?" to "How can I log debugging messages from an IE Browser Helper Object written in C++? in Windows XP-7"

I've inherited some code that just uses logError() and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could you post the code you are using for logging? Both the initialization and the actual logging.

Comment: If your BHO runs in a low level privilege process, that may be "as expected". Did you try to disable "protected mode"?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. They made me think and actually change the question...

Comment: Implement a NewlogError function, using simple fopen/fwrite/fclose calls and use the `C:\Users\YOURUSERID\AppData\LocalLow` directory. You could use the Thread Identifier if the file name.

Comment: Thank you, manuell, I will try that. In the meantime, I've found out how to attach the visual studio debugger to running processes and it works for me now. It's not the perfect solution, because I would like to see debugging output even on computers where visual studio isn't installed but it works for now.